# do-try-catch many lines of code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, error-handling, try-catch

I'd like to catch errors that can be thrown by many statements, ***withouth having to write "try" at the beginning of each of them***.

What i wrote:

```
do {
    try couldThrowException1()
    try couldThrowException2()
    try couldThrowException3()
} catch {
    handleExceptions()
}
```

How I'd like to write it:

```
do {
    couldThrowException1()
    couldThrowException2()
    couldThrowException3()
} catch {        
    handleExceptions()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately thats can't be implemented in Swift for now.

You can also use

> try!

or

> try?

like this :

```
let x = try? someThrowingFunction()
let x = try! someThrowingFunction()
```

but its not safe